# when i copy files from openjfx/lib folder and paste them the files become locked

Tags: javafx

I have created a JavaFX project that I want to upload to GitHub along with its source code and jar file. To run the jar file, I used the following command:

```
java --module-path path/to/openjfx/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar fileName.jar
```

Since the command requires the path to the lib folder of openjfx, I wanted to copy the lib folder and upload it to GitHub. My goal was to specify the relative path instead of the absolute path.

However, every time I tried to copy the files using a GUI, terminal, or logging in as a root user from terminal, they became locked. Using the `chmod` command to unlock the files did not work.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this issue?

Comment: Use [tag:maven] and the `javafx:run` command provided by the [`javafx-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin).